# strange behavior while sorting vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std, std-pair

I am populating the following vector with non-negative integers for a codejam problem:

```
vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > v;
```

Following way of sorting fails the submission:

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](auto a,auto b){
    return a.first < b.first;
});
```

But if i just change the sorting as below:

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
```

The submission passes.

What's wrong with the lamda function that I am using for sorting?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you only comparing `first` in your lambda?  `pair` also has a `second` member.

Comment: "What's wrong" depends on what you want to achieve. your lambda only takes the first element into account, but [`std::pair`'s default comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) compares both elements.

Comment: @NathanOliver. each element of vector is an interval (starting minute and ending minute). I also need to know original index after sorting, so I am storing it in inner pair. [start,(end,index)]. I need to know overlapped intervals, so I am sorting it only on start time of interval.

Comment: Thanks @churill. This link is helpful.

Comment: The next time please  be more specific, for instance about the meaning of "submission".  "The program generates correct/wrong" results would be more informative. Until I read the accepted answer, I was sure you talked about a compilation error.

Comment: @zkoza. Thanks for the advice. It is helpful. I shall be careful in future. The use of word "submission" was in the context of "codejam" (a speed programming completion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda only takes the first element into account, but obivously a pair consists of two elements. With your lambda pairs with identical first but different second elements will be considered as equal. Thus their relative order after sorting is unspecified.

If you want to sort data like the following:

```
{1, {1, 1}},
{0, {2, 2}},
{1, {3, 3}},
```

Then the first and last item are considered equal and sorting can either produce

```
{0, {2, 2}},
{1, {1, 1}},
{1, {3, 3}},
```

or

```
{0, {2, 2}},
{1, {3, 3}},
{1, {1, 1}},
```

---

But [`std::pair`'s default comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) compares the first *and* second element.

Comment: Excellent answer. Couldn't be better. Thanks a lot.